# multiple file select in file upload not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, file-upload, ajax-upload

I am using file upload control from `http://valums.com/ajax-upload/` and it says it works with multiple file selection. However, it does not work on IE8. I tried the same in FF and it works fine with it.

Is there something like IE8 doesnt support multiple file selection?

Answer (score 1):

Try uploadify, works well for multiple file uploads on IE/FF and Chrome.

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: Is it supported in asp.net 1.1 with c#. My application is in 1.1 c#.

Answer (score 0):

Its and old library. Most browsers dont support some methods used inside. Try this http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: That doesn't support multiple file uploads in IE8 or IE9 https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support

Answer (score 0):

Try [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) and you can have multiple file selection n IE8 too which I'm currently using from past 1yr without any problem.

And coming to your question it dosen't support IE for multiple selection.